# Classification of equilibria

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a system of differential equations which have an equilibrium point with eigenvalues $\lambda_{1} = 0$ and $\lambda_{2} < 0$. What type of equilibrium does this point have?

Comment: Hint: The solution would be of the form of $x(t) = c_1 e^{0t} v_1 + c_2 e^{\lambda_2 t} v_2$ ($v_1, v_2$ are eigenvectors). That gives you?

Comment: Is this a node?

Comment: See: http://www.sosmath.com/diffeq/system/linear/eigenvalue/zero/zero.html. If you post the system, I can draw a phase portrait to make it easier to analyze.

Comment: Wouldn't you need the classification of the equilibrium point in order to draw the phase portrait? The system I have is $$\dot{x} = (by - \alpha)x, \quad \dot{y} = \beta y\left(1-\frac{y}{\gamma}\right)-axy.$$ Where $a, b, \alpha, \beta, \gamma > 0$.

Comment: There are three critical points to this system: $(x, y) = ~(0, 0), ~(0, \gamma), ~\dfrac{\beta}{a}\left(1 - \dfrac{\alpha}{b \gamma}\right)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the system:

$$\begin{align}
x' & = (b~ y - \alpha)~x \\
y' & = \beta~ y \left(1 - \dfrac{y}{\gamma} \right) - a~ x~ y  \\
\end{align}$$

We find three critical points as:

$$(x, y) = ~(0, 0), ~(0, \gamma ), ~ \left(\dfrac{\beta}{a} \left( 1 - \dfrac{\alpha}{b~ \gamma} \right), \dfrac{\alpha}{b} \right)$$

If we find the Jacobian of the system, we have:

$$J(x,y) = \begin{bmatrix}b~y - \alpha & b~ x\\-a~ y & ~~~-\beta - a~ x - \dfrac{2~ \beta ~y}{\gamma}\end{bmatrix}$$

Now, evaluate the Jacobian at each critical point, find the eigenvalues and classify them.

The eigenvalues are given by:

- $(x, y) = (0, 0),~ \lambda_1 = \beta, ~\lambda_2 = -\alpha$
- $(x, y) = (0, \gamma ), ~ \lambda_1 = -\beta , ~\lambda_2 = \alpha - b~ \gamma$
- $(x, y) = \left(\dfrac{\beta}{a} \left( 1 - \dfrac{\alpha}{b~ \gamma} \right), \dfrac{\alpha}{b} \right)$, $\lambda_{1,2} = \dfrac{a~ \beta~ \alpha~ \pm ~ \sqrt{a^2~ ~\beta~ \alpha~(~\beta~ \alpha + 4~ b \alpha~ \gamma - 4 b^2 ~\gamma^2}~)~}{2 a b \gamma}$

Using your constraints, lets choose each parameter to be an increasing prime ($\gt 0$), so our system would be:

$$x' = (2y-3)x, y' = 5 y(1-y/7)-11 x y$$

Our three critical points (verify using general result above) are:

$$(x, y) = (0,0), (0, 7), \left( \dfrac{5}{14}, \dfrac{3}{2} \right)$$

You can use the above to calculate the eigenvalues.

A phase portrait validates these results:

[image]

Note: None of the eigenvalues is zero.

Comment: Thanks, a few questions: how would you classify the third equilibrium point? And how do you know the direction of time in the portrait?

Comment: You would have to do an analysis based on the parameters and consider various cases where eigenvalues are real and/or imaginary. You know the direction by the direction of the arrows. Pick any starting point on the phase portrait and follow the trajectory. To calculate these, you would calculate $\dfrac{y'}{x'}$, pick some numbers and this would tell you direction and magnitude of the arrows. Regards